# Control space between (table) float environment and head

Tags: spacing, floats, ctable

does someone know how to control the distance between a table and the head of a document page defined by the actual textheight? Somehow it only works for figures (figure 3.4) not for tables.
As I usually place the tables on top of the text pages I do have different starting points of on text pages and pages that start with a table.

Thanks for any hint!

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{scrbook}

\usepackage{framed, xcolor, graphicx}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}


\usepackage{fix-cm}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{\fontsize{9.5pt}{13.5pt}\selectfont}
\g@addto@macro\footnotesize{\fontsize{8.5pt}{13pt}\selectfont}
\g@addto@macro\footnoterule{\vskip0.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother


\usepackage[paperheight=22.5cm,paperwidth=14.8cm,showframe]{geometry} 
\geometry{includeheadfoot,top=1.5cm,headsep=6mm,bottom=0.5cm,footskip=13mm,
textwidth=11.3cm,inner=1.6cm,dvips,twoside}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize\thepage\sffamily{ }|{ }\footnotesize{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize\sffamily{\rightmark}{ }|{ }\rmfamily\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm} 
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} 

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[labelfont=it,textfont=it,singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedright]{caption}

\begin{document}
\ctable[cap = Regionen Ranking (\textit{Foreign News}-Studie),caption = Regionen Ranking (\textit{Foreign News}-Studie),label = tab:RegionalRankingForeignNews, doinside = \tiny, pos=t, captionskip = 2ex]     {lcccccccc}
{\tnote[]{\scriptsize Quelle:} \tnote[a]{\scriptsize Die Darstellung der Ränge entspricht folgender Lesart: Rang \textsubscript{Berichtsregion}/Rang\textsubscript{Akteursursprungsregion}.}}
{\toprule 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Medienberichtsregion/ Akteurursprungsregion\tmark} \\
\cmidrule(rl){2-9}
Weltregion & Nordamerika & Lateinamerika & Afrika & Naher Osten & Asien& Osteuropa & Westeuropa & Int. Allg. \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule (rl){3-3}\cmidrule (rl){4-4}\cmidrule (rl){5-5}\cmidrule (rl){6-6}\cmidrule (rl){7-7}\cmidrule (rl){8-8}\cmidrule (rl){9-9}
Nordamerika \tmark & 1/1 & 6/7 & 5/5 & 2/2 & 4/4 & 7/3 & 2/6 & 8/8 \\
Lateinamerika & 3/3 & 1/1 & 6/6 & 4/4 & 5/6 & 6/6 & 2/2 & 8/6 \\
Afrika & 5/5 & 8/8 & 1/1 & 2/2 & 5/6 & 7/7 & 3/3 & 5/4 \\
Naher Osten & 3/2 & 6/8 & 4/4 & 1/1 & 5/5 & 7/3 & 2/6 & 8/7 \\
Asien & 3/3 & 8/8 & 5/6 & 4/2 & 1/1 & 6/7 & 2/3 & 7/5 \\
Osteuropa & 6/6 & 8/8 & 7/7 & 4/6 & 3/4 & 1/1 & 2/2 & 4/3 \\
Westeuropa & 2/2 & 8/8 & 5/7 & 3/3 & 5/6 & 4/4 & 1/1 & 7/5 \\
Rang \textsubscript{Region/Akteur} & 3/2 & 7/8 & 5/6 & 2/1 & 4/5 & 6/4 & 1/3 & 8/7 \\
Rang \textsubscript{Gesamt} & 3 & 7 & 6 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 8 \\
 \bottomrule}

\begin{figure}[ht] 
\captionsetup{margin=1cm}
\captionabove[Internationale Informations- und Kommunikationsbeziehungen {Internationale Informations- und Kommunikationsbeziehungen}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[draft, width=9.3cm]{CommunicationFlow}\\
\end{center}
\noindent \hspace*{1cm}Quelle:
\label{fig:CommunicationFlow}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: What type of control are you looking for?

Comment: Can you show a minimal working example which show this behavior? A float doesn't care for its content. If `figure` work as expected, the `table` also should.

Comment: A command that defines the space above the caption. I know that there are a lot to define the distance between paragraphs and tables, tables and texts ect. Here it seems that there is a spacing is special for a ctable and the top headline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are searching for the document class option `captions=tableheading`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,final,captions=tableheading]{scrbook}
...
```

Captions in KOMA-Script will be leaded by `\abovecaptionskip` (default value = 10pt) and followed by `\belowcaptionskip` (default value = 0pt), but only if the caption is **below** the content. If the caption is **above** the content, both skips will be swapped.

How does KOMA-Script knows if the caption is above or below the content? You have either use global document class options like `captions=tableheading` to tell KOMA-Script that captions in tables should be treated as if they are above the table. Or you have to use the commands `\captionabove` or `\captionbelow`. However, you can't use `\captionabove` with ctables, so you have to use the global document class option instead.